# Laravel Livewire bind model Carbon attribute

Tags: laravel, casting, date-formatting, laravel-livewire

I'm using Laravel Livewire v2 and I need to bind a form date input to a model Carbon attribute in the backend Livewire component, but it seems to be impossible due date formatting.

To be more precise:

- when selecting a date the form date input picker livewire make a api call sending the correct date (e.g.: `2020-02-02`)
- the Livewire component correctly receive and pass the string value to the model
- the model cast the string to a Carbon object and assign it to its fillable attribute
- the Livewire component try to send back to the client the data but it doesn't perform a `->format('Y-m-d')` format on the Carbon object, so a serialized date object is sent
- when object is unserialized fronted receive e.g. `2012-12-25T20:30:00.000000+04:00 MSK`
- the date input break

I also found that in Livewire v1 it was possible to cast properties ([link](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/1.x/properties#casting-properties)) using key-value array or custom casting methods, but this has been removed in v2 ([link](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/upgrading#casters)); there is an example with `hydrate`/`dehydrate` methods to achieve the same effect but the example cover the case of a component property, not a nested one as in my case.

Is there a way to cast a model date prop or to add a format when sending data back to client?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### Update (2020-10-15)

Since Livewire v2.3, Model Casting now works when binding to model attributes directly (aka `wire:model`).

All you need to do is go to your model and provide your date casting, lets take a `Post` model as an example:

```php
class Post extends Model
{
    protected $casts = [
        'published_at' => 'date:Y-m-d'
    ];
}
```

This will let Livewire know that your `published_at` field should be serialized in the format `Y-m-d` to work with it client-side, and to convert it back into a `Carbon` (`DateTime`) instance whenever its updated.

Now, you can safely attach it to your `<input>` field:

```html
<input type="date" wire:model="published_at" />
```

### Old Answer

Currently, there’s a pending PR that aims to resolve this for Livewire v2. It would help a lot if you go and support it :)

https://github.com/livewire/livewire/pull/1665